# How to add a dynamic card view on top of recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an application which displays posts. These posts have comments,
when a user logs in to the application I am querying database and I am displaying the comments. But when a user enters a new comment, I have display it dynamically to the user and then later When the user logs in again I will query the comments from database. How can I display a card view dynamically when user clicks submit button? all suggestions are welcome.

My Adapter Class:

```
public class ToadlineCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToadlineCommentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;
    List<CommentDataStore> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    public ToadlineCommentAdapter(Context context, List<CommentDataStore> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        mContext = context;


    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_comment_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setClickListener1(SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1) {
        this.clickListener1 = clickListener1;
    }


    // View Holder object for Recycler View
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

        TextView  commentUserName, commentDays, commentDescription, commentAgreeCount, commentDisAgreeCount;
        ImageView commentImage;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
            commentImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNoOfDays);
            commentDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentDescription);
            commentAgreeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAgreeCount);
            commentDisAgreeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisAgreeCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.itemClicked(view, getPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            onClick(itemView);

        }
    }


    public interface ClickListener {

        public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Let  me know if you need more information.

My Activity:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTimeline);
    mComments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewNewCommentDescription);
    mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserNewComment);
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCommentSubmit);

    commentProfileImageHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHashMapProfileImage");
    commentDaysHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHashMapDays");
    commentDescriptionHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHashMapDescription");
    commentUserNameHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHashMapUserName");
    commentAgreeCountHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHasMapAgree");
    commentDisAgreeCountHashMap = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CommentHashMapDisAgree");

    ToadlineCommentAdapter adapter1 = new ToadlineCommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData2());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.setClickListener(this);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));


  mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredCommentText = mComments.getText().toString();

                if (enteredCommentText != null) {
                    if (enteredCommentText.equals("") || enteredCommentText.startsWith(" ")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.empty_comment_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else {

                        new RegisterCheck().execute();

                    }
                }
            }
        });

     }

    public static List<CommentDataStore> getData2() {

    List<CommentDataStore> data = new ArrayList<>();

    Bitmap[] commentProfileImage = commentProfileImageDownload;
    ArrayList<String> commentUserName1 = newCommentUserName;
    ArrayList<String> commentDays1 = newCommentDays;
    ArrayList<String> commentDescription1 = newCommentDescription;
    ArrayList<String> commentAgreeCount1 = newCommentAgreeCount;
    ArrayList<String> commentDisAgreeCount1 = newCommentDisAgreeCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < commentProfileImage.length && i < commentUserName1.size() && i < commentDays1.size() && i < commentDescription1.size(); i++) {
    CommentDataStore current = new CommentDataStore();

    current.commentProfileImageLink = commentProfileImage[i];
    current.commentUserName = commentUserName1.get(i);
    current.commentDays = commentDays1.get(i);
    current.commentDescription = commentDescription1.get(i);
    current.commentAgreeCount = commentAgreeCount1.get(i);
    current.commentDisAgreeCount = commentDisAgreeCount1.get(i);
    data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
    }


   public class RegisterCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements ToadlineCommentAdapter.ClickListener {

        private HttpURLConnection conn;
        private String
                text;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


     if (response != null) {

     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);

    commentContent = jsonObject.getString("content");
    commenterId = jsonObject.getString("commenterId");
    commenterName = jsonObject.getString("commenterName");
    commenterPhotos = jsonObject.getString("commenterPhotos");
    commentCreatedDate = jsonObject.getString("dateCreated");
    newCommentDescription.add(commentContent);
    newCommentUserName.add(commenterName);

    ToadlineCommentAdapter adapter1 = new ToadlineCommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData2());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.setClickListener(CommentActivity.this);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    }
     }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using List so you can add new data into List 0 index on submit button

```
data.add(0, yourObject);
```

then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to notify adapter that data is changed

this way your new object will be added at first position of recycle view

Comment: I need to add this from another class, submit button is in activity, how can I do the same from there?

Comment: you need to add data into List which is paasing to ToadlineCommentAdapter from Activity, and from there you need to call <ToadlineCommentAdapter_Object>.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: If you can upload your Activity I will show it by modifying it

Comment: I will try doing it. If I don get it I will upload my activity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to add new comment to the adapter before the list gets synchronized with the comments in the database later on.

Just use

```
toadlineCommentAdapter.add(new CommentDataStore("New comment"), 0);
toadlineCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to add the new object as the first element of the adapter referenced where you instantiate it.

For example, in your activity you can do:

```java
ToadlineCommentAdapter toadlineCommentAdapter = new ToadlineCommentAdapter(mContext, commentsList);

newCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toadlineCommentAdapter.add(new CommentDataStore("New comment"), 0);
        toadlineCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Later on, when you synchronize your comments with the database, you can do something like:

```java
toadlineCommentAdapter.clear();
toadlineCommentAdapter.addAll(newlyFetchedCommentsList);
toadlineCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The exact implementation depends on how you instantiate new CommentDataStore object and how you get the data from your database.

Comment: I tried this but unsuccessful. Can you see the updated code and give me some suggestions

Comment: First of all, your implementation of extended AsyncTask is wrong, see the docs of it. Second, create global reference to ToadlineCommentAdapter in your CommentActivity to always have the same instance of it. Third, I don't see implementation of onClickListener to your mSubmit Button.

Comment: I have not added complete code since its too long. I have implemented async task correctly. I will try with global instance of adapter.

Comment: Did you implement this adapter thing? Now, in the onClickListener above the line ```new RegisterCheck().execute();``` you can add your new CommentDataStore object to this adapter with the solution provided above. Using the debugger could help you track the changes to your adapter to see if the new object your are adding is present where it should be. If you have more problems, please describe them in detail so we know what "does not work".

Comment: I am adding New comment data store object in onPostExecute of async task.. I need to add the new item after the execution of asynctask

Comment: Yeah, but as I understood you wanted to do it _before_ your AsyncTask finishes ;) 1) User adds a comment 2) comment starts to upload to your db 3) in the meantime, you add the comment to the list so it seems instant 4) the AsyncTask finishes and you get your comments synchronized with your backend. Is that right? Btw, It's not clear how you actually send this comment to the backend...

Comment: Have you had any success with my answer? ;)